# move codeigniter project from localhost to live server

Tags: codeigniter

Trying to move the codeigniter project from laptop server to live server. Uploaded the files in **Public_HTML** and I modified the **config.php**, **base_url**, **.htaccess** as needed and also upgrade the **Database**... when i run project default controller called correctly when other controller can not call this message show `404 Page Not Found`. **config.php** and **.htaccess** files update as correct information. This same project run successfully on Local or Desktop server but produce Error on live server `404 Page Not Found` home controller (default controller) call but other controller not call.

Comment: You should try check error log files, there you can check what is actual error.

Comment: maybe your controller name starts with the small letter.

Comment: base_url issue, incorrect routing, bad htaccess, files thought to be uploaded but not actually, controller class name not the same as file name in the formation `class Some_controller` and `Some_controller.php`

Comment: you need to rename the base_url to your config.php. remove the localhost and add your new url.

Comment: what is your site url ?

Comment: server is case sensitive whereas local system is not

Comment: Done. Find error my controller name start with small letter.

Answer (score 0):

What is your server? And whats your configuration file?
Make sure you enable mod rewite if you are using apache

a2enmod rewrite

Answer (score 0):

Have you removed index.php from url? Try to access another controller like this.

```
<domain>/index.php/<controllername>
```